# Tomcat webapp deployment issue

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7

I am deploying a tomcat webapp as part of an environment build which seems to be failing. I tried to start the app via the GUI but I get the following error:

```
Attempting to start application via the GUI:
FAIL - Application at context path /mmc-console-3.3.1 could not be started
```

So I tried deploying a sample app which worked. The `mmc` webapp works in a different environment.

I looked at the [error log](http://pastebin.com/fMimMJTe) but I am unable to identify the exact cause (I'm not a java developer).

Can someone assist with identifying the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the attached error log this what I believe is the problem:

Application not able to start because -> creation of sessionFactory fails because -> creation of bean 'repository' fails -> because not able to initialise lucene (unable to initialize query handler: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex@2713affb

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make too much sense to me. Is is suggesting the app is broken? or something else?

Comment: yes the app needs lucene to be setup properly and hence it is not able to come up. Just follow the stack trace you have posted.